# :input selector not finding anything for form

Tags: jquery, forms, input, selector

I have an img that when clicked, points to a form using a custom attribute, and that form then submits it's hidden inputs via .post

Here is the code:

```
$("img.imgsubmit").live('click',function(){
    var msg = $(this).attr('title');
    var r=confirm(msg+'?');
    if (r==false){return false;}
    var form = '#'+$(this).attr('imgsubmit');
    var url = $(form).attr('action');
    var output = OutputName($(form).attr('output'));
    $("#"+output).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Working..." />');
    // get post values
    var data = {}; // define data object
    $(':input',this).each(function(index){
            alert(this); // NEVER HAPPENS
            var key = $(this).attr('name');
            var val = $(this).val();
            data[key] = val;
    });
    // post
    $.post(url,data, function(html) {
            $("#"+output).html(html).slideFadeShow("fast");
    });
    return false;
});
```

So everything is fine until:

```
$(':input',form).each(function(index){
        alert(this); // NEVER HAPPENS, so it's never finding all the inputs
        var key = $(this).attr('name');
        var val = $(this).val();
        data[key] = val;
});
```

I've tried all sorts of things with that first line:

```
$(':input',$(form)).each(function(index){

$(':input',form).each(function(index){

$(form+' :input').each(function(index){
```

None of it gets it to work. Basically, it's not working with the object at all to select the hidden inputs inside the form element.

**tl;dr** everything is fine except the :input selector not working when accessing the form var.

Comment: think the problem might be here:  var form = '#'+$(this).attr('imgsubmit'); Are you sure the form variable is actually capturing the form. Try giving the form an id and using something like: var form = $('form#myFormId');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a stab in the dark without seeing your markup but $("form :input") should work.

*note that it's all in quotes*

Comment: The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) recommend using `:input` within `filter` to achieve the best performance. You might try `$("form *").filter(":input")` for that reason.

Comment: I hadn't read that before, thanks for the tip kojiro. (up-voted)

Comment: Edit: Removed second suggestion per kojiro's advice and also because I was able to test the first suggestion I've made and it works.